# marquee.js stops when pressing play/stop in embedded iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, marquee, feed

I currently work on a project and implemented the marquee.js for news feed.
When i press the start/pause button in an embedded video iframe it suddenly stops and will be reactived when i press outstide the iframe content.
You can check it live [www.riftrank.com](http://www.riftrank.com)
How can i denie that behaivor from the marquee js ? The news feed should not stop when iframe button pressed. Someelse had a similiar marquee problem ?

Comment: Well... tested in Chrome: it stops, but it doesn't start again. Tested in Firefox: the marquee doesn't even start before the video is playing, nor after it started playing, and clicking on stuff makes no difference. I'm guessing there are other problems on that page than just the iframe.

Comment: on my desktop in firefox works all well just stops when pause/play - in chrome it starts after 5 seconds or hover. but you re right there must be a significant problem with that marquee.js